# Apache Camel Route is working under Windows but not Linux

Tags: apache-camel

I am executing Camel code in Windows using Eclipse and it is working fine.
However, when I execute the same code in standalone from Linux, the route has print first log but when fetching file it stops without any error.

Here is my code:

```java
from("timer://alertstrigtimer?period=90s&repeatCount=1")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "*******************************Job-Alert-System: Started: alertstrigtimer******************************" + getFileURI(getWorkFilePath(), getWorkFileName()))
    .pollEnrich(getFileURI(getWorkFilePath(), getWorkFileName()))
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "*******************************Job-Alert-System: Started: alertstrigtimer******************************" + getFileURI(getWorkFilePath(), getWorkFileName()))
    .choice()
        .when(header("CamelFileName").isNull())
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "No File")
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    log.info("Job-Alert-System: No Date File Exist!!!! Calculate 15 Minutes Back and fetching data from Masterdata");
                    // Do something
                }
            })
        .otherwise()
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Job Alert System: Date File Loaded: ${header.CamelFileName} at ${header.CamelFileLastModified}")
            .process(new Processor() {
                // Do something by a processor
            })


public static String getFileURI(String filePath, String fileName) {
    return "file://" + filePath + "?fileName=" + fileName
        + "&preMove=$simple{file:onlyname.noext}.$simple{date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh-mm-ss}";
}
```

Here are my logs from the Linux environment:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.21.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter - Type converters loaded (core: 194, classpath: 0)
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route1 started and consuming from: timer://alertstrigtimer?period=90s&repeatCount=1
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: loadDataAndAlerts started and consuming from: direct://loadDataAndAlerts
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.21.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.664 seconds
[Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - timer://alertstrigtimer] INFO route1 - *******************************Job-Alert-System: Started: alertstrigtimer******************************file:///shared/wildfly/work-files/alerts?fileName=LastExecutionTime_JobAlerts.txt&preMove=.2020-10-12T06-48-16
```

It stops here. It creates a directory structure, but does not move forward.

Logs from My Local Machine:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.21.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter - Type converters loaded (core: 194, classpath: 5)
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route1 started and consuming from: timer://alertstrigtimer?period=90s&repeatCount=1
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: loadDataAndAlerts started and consuming from: direct://loadDataAndAlerts
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.21.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.845 seconds
[Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - timer://alertstrigtimer] INFO route1 - *******************************Job-Alert-System: Started: alertstrigtimer******************************file://null?fileName=null&preMove=null.2020-10-12T10-28-51
[Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - timer://alertstrigtimer] INFO route1 - Job Alert System: Date File Loaded: null.2020-10-12T10-28-51 at 0
```

It creates directory structure in addition to a file, but the file is not present and it moves forward.

Comment: Methods that resolve file paths may produce different results -> eg. getFileURI
There might be an issue with firewall or closed ports

Comment: @Lukasz: It is same environment path. Updated code